# Get value from an html form and store it in mysql db through django

Tags: mysql, django-templates, django-views

I need the code for updating data to database(mysql) through  html submit button in Python/Django.need view.py contents with html code.consider I am having a table with bookname,authorname & publishername i need to update the values these values through an html submit button.

Plese help me in this..I am new to this framework...not able to get through.

It will be more thankfull if you send me a code for edit a table  in mysql througn Django/Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
   book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True)
   author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True)
   publisher_name = models.CharField(max_length = 32, unique = True)
```

forms.py

import Book from your path

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class = Book
```

view.py

```
def save_book(request):  
  form = BookForm
  if request.POST:
     form = BookForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
  return render_to_response('book.html.html',{'form': form} ,                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

book.html

```
<body>
<form action="." method="post" name="book" id="book">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr><td>{{form.book_name.label}}</td><td>{{form.book_name}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{{form.author_name.label}}</td><td>{{form.author_name}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{{form.publisher_name.label}}</td><td>{{form.publisher_name}}</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="button" name="btnSave" id="bntSave" value="Save"  class = "default2"/></td>
</table>
</body>
```

url.py
call your url